# Using for loops to create multiple lists with lower lists

Tags: list, python-2.7, for-loop, append

I have a certain function:

def create4(n):

```
output = []
for i in range(n):
    output.append(range(1+i,1))
return output
```

I want it to produce:

[[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5]]

for when I print create4(5). How would I change my for loop make the code produce the desired output?

Comment: Hi!  I'm not sure that asking these questions is helping the way it should, unfortunately.  If you'd understood the answers to your previous questions -- or how the `range` function works -- this would be straightforward.  It might be worthwhile spending some time playing at the console to get a sense for how the arguments to `range` affect the output.

Comment: This question is asked several times by the same user

Answer (score 0):

Add a second `for` loop. The first `for` will iterate over each nested `list`. The second `for` will add the elements.

```
def create4(n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        output.append([])
        for j in range(i, n):
            output[i] += [j + 1]
    return output

print create4(5)
```